# About the proof: $\mathbb Q$ is not locally compact

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation, compactness

$$\mathbb Q \text{ is not locally compact.}$$

Proof by Brian M. Scott on this [answer:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1465615/is-this-proof-correct-mathbbq-is-not-locally-compact)

> Suppose that $C$ is a compact subset of $\Bbb Q$ with $0$ that contains an open nbhd of $0$; then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\cap\Bbb Q\subseteq C$. Let $f:\Bbb Q\to\Bbb R$ be the identity map; $f$ is continuous, so $f[C]$ is compact, and $f[C]\supseteq f[(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\cap\Bbb Q]=(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\cap\Bbb Q$. But $\Bbb R$ is Hausdorff, so the compact set $f[C]$ must be closed, and therefore $f[C]\supseteq\operatorname{cl}_{\Bbb R}\big((-\epsilon,\epsilon)\cap\Bbb Q\big)=[\epsilon,\epsilon]$. This, however, is impossible, since $f[C]$ is countable, and $[\epsilon,\epsilon]$ is not.

- Why there exists and $\epsilon>0$ such that $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\cap\Bbb Q\subseteq C$ ?

and

- Why *$f[C]\supseteq[\epsilon,\epsilon]$ with $f[C]$ is countable, and $[\epsilon,\epsilon]$ is not*

is the contradiction?

please someone enlighten me!

Thanks in advance

---

Comment: For the first bullet, that is the definition of the statement "$C$ contains an open nbhd of $0$". For the second bullet, every subset of a countable set is countable.

Comment: @LeeMosher If you posted that as an answer I would upvote it.

Comment: @LeeMosher but why $f[C]$ is countable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first bullet, that is the definition of the statement "$C$ contains an open nbhd of $0$".

For the second bullet, you need some set theory: every subset of a countable set is countable; and every image of a countable set under a function is countable. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, it's subset $C$ is countable, and the image $f(C)$ is countable, so the subset $[-\epsilon,\epsilon] \subset f(C)$ is countable. However, $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ is not countable, which gives the contradiction.

Comment: I understand, $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ is countable **!** $([-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ is finite), right?

Comment: No, $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ is not countable. That's how the argument by contradiction ends: from the assumption you derive that $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ is countable, which contradicts the mathematical fact that $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ is not countable.

Comment: In my comment I wrote this **!** sign which means contradiction, $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ is finite, right?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set